# OSGI ConfigurationAdmin is null while retrieving using getServiceReference in AEM

Tags: osgi, aem, osgi-bundle

I'm working on a use case that involves accessing properties of other bundles that are not part of the current bundle. In order to achieve this, I have to modify the permissions of the current AEM bundle (AEM 6.2). I see that ConditionalPermissionAdmin of OSGi service is the way forward.

Approach Reference: http://moi.vonos.net/java/osgi-security/

I have the below code, that intends to retrieve the ConditionalPermissionAdmin but
some unknown reason the this always null.

```
public class Activator implements BundleActivator {

   private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Activator.class);

   private ConditionalPermissionAdmin conditionalPermissionAdmin;

  @Override
  public final void start(final BundleContext bundleContext) {
    try {
        conditionalPermissionAdmin = getConditionalPermissionAdmin(bundleContext);
        if (conditionalPermissionAdmin != null) {
            LOG.info("{0} conditionalPermissionAdmin ", conditionalPermissionAdmin.getClass());
           /* pseudocode */
        }
        LOG.info("{0} started", bundleContext.getBundle().getSymbolicName());
    }  catch (Exception ex) {
        LOG.error(ex.getMessage());
    }
  }

  private ConditionalPermissionAdmin getConditionalPermissionAdmin(BundleContext context) throws BundleException {
    ServiceReference ref = context.getServiceReference(ConditionalPermissionAdmin.class.getName());
    ConditionalPermissionAdmin permissionAdmin = null;
    if (ref != null) {
        permissionAdmin = (ConditionalPermissionAdmin) context.getService(ref);
    }
    return permissionAdmin;
  }

  @Override
  public final void stop(final BundleContext bundleContext) {
    LOG.info("{0} stopped", bundleContext.getBundle().getSymbolicName());
  }
}
```

[image]

I don't see any build or runtime issues. Even the bundle is in good shape.

[image: Bundle Status]

This low-level API is not the best approach as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21103889/4802007). But I'm unsure on the Declarative Services approach for permission.

Heads up --> I'm new to OSGi concepts and implementation.

References:

- [How to use OSGi getServiceReference() right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2732456/how-to-use-osgi-getservicereference-right)
- [OSGi ConfigurationAdmin Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45222221/osgi-configurationadmin-service)

Comment: 1. what AEM version are you on? 2. could you please elaborate on your usecase? and why a user-based permission would not work?

Comment: @AhmedMusallam - I'm on AEM 6.2. I have updated the description with the use case. The user-based permissions won't work as this not something related to content.

Comment: when you say "accessing properties of other bundles" what do you mean? what is it you're trying to access? OSGI config?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though I do not fully understand the use-case and why a service user or user-based access in general would not work, here is what I found:

The [felix framework security documentation](http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-framework-security.html) suggest that you need to install the `org.apache.felix.framework.security` bundle, which is not installed by default with AEM (at least looking at my vanilla 6.3 instance)

It's listed under "Framework Security" in the Felix subprojects install page: http://felix.apache.org/downloads.cgi#subprojects

The issue is that there are no implementations of the OSGI `org.osgi.service.condpermadmin.ConditionalPermissionAdmin` in your instance. And that's why you need the felix security bundle.

Comment: Awesome. This worked, the reason indeed was related to missing implementations related ConditionalPermissionAdmin. Installing `org.apache.felix.framework.security` bundle just worked like magic. This was missing in AEM 6.2 as well.

Answer (score 4):

Generally in OSGi it is possible that a service reference is not (yet) available.
So simply getting the current service reference is very likely to fail because of timing issues.

One valid low level approach is to start a ServiceTracker and react when the service becomes available. This is quite difficult to do right though.

So as you already heard of using DS is the best and recommended approach.

Comment: Since, the issue was related missing implementation for ConditionalPermissionAdmin. Since that's resolved by installing missing `org.apache.felix.framework.security` bundle, I can now the implement same using DS.

Comment: Having an implementation for ConditionalPermissionAdmin is of course an important first step! But the problem that Christian indicated still exists... even when you have an implementation installed, you can't predict or enforce the order in which services become available. Therefore if you simply request the service at a single point in time, you may get null because the service doesn't exist *yet*. This is why DS is recommended.